# How to upload a large string in an Azure Blob?

Tags: python, timeout, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to work with Azure, and now I'm stuck in a problem while storing my data in the storage account.
I have three strings and want to store each of them in a separate blob. With the first two, my code works fine, but the third one causes some retries and ends with a timeout.
My code is running within an Azure function.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str.      = '<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING>',
    container_name = '<CONTAINER_NAME>',
    blob_name.     = '<NAME_OF_BLOB>',
)

dic_blob_props = blob_client.upload_blob(
    data      = '<INFORMATION_THAT_SHOULD_GO_TO_THE_BLOB>', 
    blob_type = "BlockBlob", 
    overwrite = True,
)
```

The for the first two strings everything works fine but the third fails. The strings have the following length:

```
len(s_1) = 1246209
len(s_2) = 8794086
len(s_3) = 24518001
```

Most likely it is because the third string is too long, but there must be a way to save it, right?
I have already tried to set the timeout time within the `.upload_blob` method by `timeout=600`, but this has not changed the result at all, nor the time until a new attempt to write is made.

The error is:

```
Exception: ServiceResponseError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
```

If you have any ideas on the problem pleast let me know :-)

Comment: How long did your third string take to process?

Comment: it stops and repeats the process after ~40 seconds

Comment: @BowmanZhu, sorry, missed to tag you :-)

Comment: ok, will do a test.

Comment: @BowmanZhu, thanks
btw. the storring of the first two strings takes only ~2 respectively ~10 seconds.

Comment: @BowmanZhu, I split the string in parts of 10,000,000 characters and it worked... I do not see why the whole string can't be stored to the storage...

Comment: Hi, you can have a look of the method I post, It dont have any time out error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem disappeared after I deployed the function in the cloud. It seems that there was a problem debugging with Visual Studio code.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I don't have the problem. You can have a look of my code:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream],) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('This code is to upload a string to a blob.')
    s_3 = "x"*24518001
    outputblob.set(s_3)
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "The string already been uploaded to a blob.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{test}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test1/{test}.txt",
      "connection": "str",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "str":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

Then I hit the endpoint `http://localhost:7071/api/bowman`, it uploads the string to blob and don't have time out error:

[image]

So, I think the problem is related with the method you use.

Comment: Thanks for testing it and showing the example. I will revise mine and then see if it works :-)

Comment: Hello again,
the problem disappeared after I deployed the function in the cloud. It seems that there was/is a problem debugging with Visual Studio code.
Thanks for your help and your comments :-)

Comment: @Pet In fact, I also upload on local.Usually we use binding to interact with storage.

Comment: @Pet Do you still encounter problems with timeout locally using the method I provided?

Comment: Hello, actually I aborted the attempt with your solution because I couldn't find a way to use a 'customer provided key'.
For local testing I divided the file into parts and the problem disappeared.

Comment: @Pet Ok, It is no problem.:)