# Solve timeout errors on file uploads with new azure.storage.blob package

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I had to upgrade a docker container that was using the older version of microsoft azure's python packages to download data from an api, then upload a json to Azure Blob Storage. So since the pip install of the former "azure" metapackage is no longer allowed I have to use the new standalone packages (azure-storage-blob==12.6.0).

Switching from the function "create_blob_from_path" from the blockblobservice integrated in the old "azure" package, to the new standalone package and BlobClient.upload() fails on larger files with a timeout error that completely ignores the timeout parameter of the function.

I get a ServiceResponseError with the msg "Connection aborted / The write operation timed out"

Is there any way to solve that error ?

The new function feels like a huge step backwards from create_blob_from_path, the absence of progress_callback mainly is deplorable...

Comment: What's the size of your file? And there is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63599438/13308381), have you tried to deploy the function in the cloud?

Comment: @PamelaPeng yes I've seen this similar issue but I don't use visual studio code and get the same result from my local script and docker container.

As for the file size It's probably around ~10Mb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *correct* solution, if your control flow allows it, seems to be setting the `max_single_put_size` to something smaller (like 4MB) when you create the `BlobClient`. You can do this with a keyword parameter when calling the constructor.

However, as near as I can tell, this parameter cannot be configured if creating a BlobClient through the `BlobClient.from_blob_url` control flow. The default value for this is 64MB, and it is easy to hit the default connection timeout before a 64MB PUT is done. In some applications, you may not have access to auth credentials for the storage account (i.e. you're just using a signed URL), so the only way to create a `BlobClient` is from a `BlobClient.from_blob_url` call.

It seems like the workaround is to set the poorly documented `connection_timeout` parameter on the `upload_blob` call, instead of the `timeout` parameter. So, something like:

```py
upload_result = block_blob_client.upload_blob(
    data,
    blob_type="BlockBlob",
    content_settings=content_settings,
    length=file_size,
    connection_timeout=600,
)
```

That parameter is documented on this page:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#other-client--per-operation-configuration

However, it is *not* currently documented on the official `BlobClient` documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python

I've filed this documentation bug: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/22936

Comment: Just to underline to anyone else reading this, connection_timeout needs to be set, especially when uploading over relatively slow connections (e.g. 1MB/sec).
The connection_timeout setting is a badly documented, badly implemented setting in the SDK.  I spent hours looking at other solutions.  I had already set max_single_put_size and other similar settings after reviewing the documentation, but upload_blob() was still failing after around 2-3 minutes.

Comment: To add a little more detail to my comment above...
The connection_timeout setting doesn't exist in any of the named parameters in upload_blob() or the functions it calls.  I only verified the solution after going through the code to the low-level send() function where the timeout sneaks in - see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/4205ea9b662ed10bc762087860c73ddcacb22f0a/sdk/core/azure-core/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py

Comment: Final comment - it is incredible to me that Microsoft have closed the github issue, they clearly don't understand the impact this issue is having.

Comment: I've had another go at raising the issue:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/23232

Comment: You can also set `connection_timeout` on the client. For example `container = ContainerClient(..., connection_timeout=120); container.upload_blob(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I tested with code as following, it uploaded the file(~10M) successfully.

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

# Upload content to block blob
with open(SOURCE_FILE, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

[image]

Comment: Mine is similar. I noticed I usually get failures when the upload transits through my VPN, it works better without "middlemen" (which in a way echoes to the similar issue you linked 
 too) 

Nevertheless, that's workarounds not solutions, it's puzzling to get a timeout and have no way to adjust it. There must be something I'm missing there. (e.g. the upload function's "timeout" integer get an integer, not, as usually implemented, a tuple for every step of the process. Maybe it's possible with a kwarg but I can't find it in the source, or the BlobServiceClient ou the BlobClient themselves)

Comment: @VincentChalmel, how do you set the timeout? can you show us the code?

Comment: @IvanYang same as yours I'm afraid, thanks for the chunks proposal, I will keep that in mind as an alternative if I get more of this errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you set the timeout value, here is an example of upload blob with timeout setting:

```
with open(upload_file_path,"rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data=data,timeout=600) # timeout is set to 600 seconds
```

If the timeout is ignored, another workaround is that you can upload blob in chunk, code like below:

```
# upload data in chunk
block_list=[]
chunk_size=1024
with open(upload_file_path,'rb') as f:
   
   while True:
        read_data = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not read_data:
            break # done
        blk_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        blob_client.stage_block(block_id=blk_id,data=read_data) 
        block_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=blk_id))
        

blob_client.commit_block_list(block_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_service_client.max_single_put_size = 4*1024*1024
blob_service_client.timeout = 180
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name) 
container_client.upload_blob(data=file, name=key, max_concurrency=12)
```

Also check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python